# Given a probabilistic context-free grammar, how can I generate synthetic sentences with largest probability?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Let's say I have a probabilistic context-free grammar, I need to generate some synthetic sentences. The way I want to generate is as follows:

sentence with largest probability, sentence with second largest probability.... in a sequence.

Is there a routine to accomplish this task? Or is it even feasible?

Comment: In what programming language?